# no change in database after update query runned in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

if I try to run my update query in c# I see no change in my database.

The weird thing is that I don't get an error message returned so I don't know what im doing wrong.

Hopefully one of you guys can spot what im doing wrong, thanks in advance

**My Code:**

```
    public static void Builder()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Opening SSH Connection...");
        // Establishing ssh connection to server where MySql is hosted
        using (var client = new SshClient("ssh_host", "ssh_username", "ssh_password"))
        {
            client.Connect();
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 22, "127.0.0.1", 3306);
                client.AddForwardedPort(portForwarded);
                portForwarded.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("SSH Connection Established!\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Opening MySql Connection...");
                // Establishing MySql connection to the database
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=22;UID=DB_login;PASSWORD=DB_password;DATABASE=DB_tablename"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MySql Connection Established!\n");
                    // Opening the Connection
                    con.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("Generating Query...");
                    // Making the Query
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET value= 1114 WHERE value_id= 4063", con);
                    Console.WriteLine("Query Generated!");
                }
                client.Disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client cannot be reached...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't show your database table column types, I assume from your code that they are numeric, in your where clause, if not, enclose the value in quotes.  Otherwise I don't see anything that stands out.

Comment: looks like you set the command, but you don't execute it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your ssh and database credentials are correct, try adding `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` to your query.

**Why? :**

You'r trying to run an `UPDATE` query but your not executing the query so (in your code) it will not do anything! :)

Add it like this:

```
                Console.WriteLine("Generating Query...");
                // Making the Query
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET value= 1114 WHERE value_id= 4063", con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Query Generated!");
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not executing the query at all. What you have is just the command declaration as below

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET..", con);
```

You also need to execute the query saying

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

See [MySQL Connector Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm) for more information